# Definite integrals estimations based on odd or even function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am about to take my final Calculus exam, and I've got a set of problems from which couple of definite integrals exercises seem to be problematic, I couldn't find similar examples in my notes from lectures. Maybe you can help me out

Also some explanation what is general rule in case of such problems would come really helpful.

[Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq21f.png)

Answer (score 1):

A really helpful thing you could do is to exploit some geometric intuition to understand what's going on- specifically we're going to use the symmetries of even and odd functions.

**Even Functions**

We call a function $f(x)$ even if the function satisfies $f(x)=f(-x)$, it seems like a pure algebraic definition but it hides some geometry in it: If we take any $x$ value (from the domain of course)- then $f(-x)$ would be equal. Graphing a function that posses such property would give you a graph which is symmetric about the y-axis. Lets for example take a famous even function: $\cos(x)$
[image: graph of cos(x)]

Now, look at how the function behaves to the right and to left of the y-axis- It is the same! So if we interpret the definite integral as finding the signed area between a curve and the x-axis- we see that for an even function, on an interval that is symmetric about $0$ (intervals of the form $[-a,a]$), we can integrate on $[0,a]$ and double our integral:

$$\int^{a}_{-a}f(x)dx=2\int^{a}_{0}f(x)dx=2\int^{0}_{-a}f(x)dx$$

**Odd Functions**

We call a function $f(x)$ odd if the function satisfies $f(-x)=-f(x)$, this property for some people is a bit harder to grasp in terms of what is the symmetry (at least I had), and it turns out that it's a symmetry around the point $(0,0)$ with respect to rotation of $180$ degrees when the origin is fixed, after rotating your graph will remain unchanged. Lets look at a famous odd function: $\sin(x)$:
[image: graph of sin(x)]

We look at the graph, how do we interpret the symmetry now? The defining property was $g(-x)=-g(x)$, then for any $x$ value in the domain, the value of $g(x)$ in the $-x$ would be the negative (or inverse with respect to addition), that is $-g(x)$! So if we now look at our problem as finding the signed area between a curve and the x-axis, and we look at an odd function on an interval symmetric about $0$ we get:

$$\int^{a}_{-a}g(x)dx=-\int^{-a}_{a}g(x)dx=0$$

That is, the areas to the right of the y-axis and to the left of the y-axis are the same, but with opposite signs so they cancel out.

---

I'll do one example from your problems. lets look at (2).

$g(x)$ is an even function and integrable on $[-10,10]$, we know that:
$$\int^{0}_{-6}g(x)dx=4$$

So from what we saw earlier we know; that for even function this equality holds:
$$\int^{a}_{-a}f(x)dx=2\int^{0}_{-a}f(x)dx$$

and for $a=6$ we get:
$$\int^{0}_{-6}g(x)dx=4\Longrightarrow\int^{6}_{-6}g(x)dx=8$$

---

**EDIT:**
I see now that the other questions ask a for more subtle use of the symmetries mentioned, so I'd also remind your of an important property of the definite integral: If $b\in[a,c]$ then:
$$\int^{c}_{a} g(x)dx = \int^{b}_{a} g(x)dx + \int^{c}_{b} g(x)dx$$